# PHP modules / extension installed in MAMP not loaded to ZSH terminal

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, mamp, zsh

I use MAMP Pro 4 and `PHP 5.6.25`

I have linked MAMP's `PHP` in to `ZSH` using an alias

`php: aliased to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.25/bin/php`

But when `phpinfo()` is executed on the above PHP version, both `mongo` and `mongodb` extensions are shown;

[image: PHPInfo result on MAMP PHP curent version]

But when `php -m` is executed on zsh terminal (iterm) I don't see the `mongodb` extension;

```
➜  ~ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
...
...
mcrypt
mhash
mongo
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
...
...
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

What should I do in order to load the missing modules in to zsh terminal?

PS: I also have a feeling that `OpenSSL` also is a different version in ZSH than to MAMP PHP

Comment: I am really desperate for some help with this!!